# Asking for a SSTP connecting configuration file for using SSTP command line

Tags: networking, network-manager, security, openvpn

Using sstp with Network Manager and DNScrypt stopped working on Ubuntu 12.04

**DNSCrypt and Network manager and using Unblockvpn's SSTP** - 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sstp-client/

- Connects the VPN but DNScrypt stops working.
- Tested with IPv4 settings: a) Automatic (VPN) and b) Automatic (VPN) addresses only with DNS server: 127.0.0.2

---

**Network manager and using OpenVPN** - Unblockvpn's configuration 256 bits encryption

- Connects the VPN but navigation and DNScrypt stop working.
- Tested with IPv4 settings: a) Automatic (VPN) and b) Automatic (VPN) addresses only with DNS server: 127.0.0.2

---

**Network manager and using OpenVPN** - Witopia's configuration *128* bits encryption

- Connects the VPN and navigation and DNScrypt keep working.
- Working only with IPv4 settings: Automatic (VPN) addresses only with DNS server: 127.0.0.2

---

**Network manager and using OpenVPN** - Witopia's configuration *256* bits encryption

- Connects the VPN but only DNScrypt stops working.
- Tested with IPv4 settings: a) Automatic (VPN) and b) Automatic (VPN) addresses only with DNS server: 127.0.0.2

---

Could you please help me with this technical issue?

`DNScrypt` keeps working in any encryption mode (128 and 256 bits) using OpenVPN command line, very stable!

I hope that `SSTP` and `OpenVPN` could be used with `DNScrypt`, it would be an extraordinary security tool!

Could you please send the Unblockvpn's SSTP connecting configuration file using SSTP command line in Linux and instructions? I think that using it with command line will let the connection functions correctly instead of using it with Network Manager.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)